# Paypal Express No Button

Tags: civicontribute

When using PayPal Express as my payment option, there is no button appearing to take the user to PayPal. I've checked everything I can imagine, cleared caches, etc. and feel that I must be missing some little thing. But, for the life of me, I have no idea.

Please help!

Comment: I am having the same issue after an upgrade to 4.6 from 4.5 and none of the answers above seem to solve it.
I also observed that the credit card payment form is on the contribution pages per default even without any card type active.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce this behaviour (showing credit card form and no paypal button) on the civicrm official test site

Answer (score 5):

Two settings that can cause this issue are:

1. The link to the button image is missing in the payment processor settings. The setting is called "Button URL" and it should normally point to https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif.
2. The page is configured for membership signups and has the option turned on to allow "Separate Membership Payment" in the contribution page's membership tab. This setting is currently incompatible with Paypal Express. In some versions of CiviCRM this setting causes the Paypal Express button to be hidden. In others an explicit error is given when clicking on the button. See: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-8221

Comment: Where could I find the place where the link to the image should be?